# Reading from a database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to pull some information from a database, and the connection is working, but for some reason it isn't recognizing my query, even though I confirmed the query in the database with SQL and had it "generate PHP code". The echo statement is coming up blank. It's a mySQL database. Thanks for your help.

```
$query = "SELECT `contact` FROM `contactinfo` WHERE member=\'Henry\'";
$contact = mysqli_query($db,$query);
echo $contact;
```

Comment: Try a `var_dump($contact)`.  `mysqli_query()` returns an object.  In your case, it is probably returning `false`, meaning your query failed.

Comment: You don't need to escape those single quotes around `Henry`.

Comment: `\'` inside double quotes (`"`) gives you `\'` when you only want `'`... but try and find tutorials on MySQLi or PDO prepared statements and bind variables

Comment: When I unescape the single quotes, this shows up: 

Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Comment: The `$contact` variable either contains a boolean value (i.e. `true` or `false`) or a `mysqli_result` object. If nothing appears on the page then it is probably `false`... `true` would display `1` on the page, and echoing the `mysqli_result` object would show an error.

Comment: @Henry because in that case it's working, and it's returning, in fact, an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$contact` contains MySQL result object you need to fetch data from this to use this in your application.

```
$query   = "SELECT `contact` FROM `contactinfo` WHERE member = 'Henry'";
$contact = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($contact)) {
  echo $row[0]; // 0 to n indicates the Column(s) Selected in SELECT Query
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! so anytime you read from a db it's read as an object, and you have to withdraw the actual data from it?

Comment: @Henry Yes its always an object, you have to fetch data from it. There are various methods available for that. The above one fetches data in array format, you can fetch it as an object as well.